# jquery .length does not return actual length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a data table where  I have a list of 6 data but it's still  returning "0" rows. Why I am not getting the exact list of rows?

```
var rowCount = $('#stockDetailModal >tbody >tr').length;
alert(rowCount);

if(rowCount=="0") {
    $("#serviceDetailModal").find("tbody").html("<tr><td colspan='10'>No Records  Found</td></tr>");
}
```

This is my code. Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: what does `rowCount` return in your alert

Comment: I have tried your code and it looks like it works: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L4x5zk4d/), maybe a misspell?

Comment: Yes, working for me also.!!  http://jsfiddle.net/0nwg3bhs/1/ Check the basic library and spelling of the code.

Comment: it should work well, unless you've misspelled your id. 

as a side note, please use "===" for comparisons, and comapre integers with integers and not strings. so `rowCount === 0`, also, you could remove the unnecessary check by using `!rowCount`

Comment: whether the table header is considered as <tr>?,because i have 5 rows returning,still its showing 6,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It should work well, unless you've misspelled your id. You have 2 ids `stockDetailModal` & `serviceDetailModal`, are both correct? and are you using both of them correctly?

Also, make sure you don't have duplicate ids.

As a side note,

- please use "===" for comparisons
- compare integers with integers and not strings, so make it `rowCount === 0`
- you could remove the unnecessary comparison (with 0) by using `!rowCount`